# javascript Image() triggers errors when downloading, unclear why

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using [Quasar](https://v1.quasar-framework.org/start/pick-quasar-flavour) with this code:

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-sm row items-start">
      <q-img
        v-for="pic in picObject"
        :key="pic.id"
        :src="pic"
        @error="reportError"
        style="height: 140px; width: 140px"
      >
        <template v-slot:default>
          <div class="absolute-bottom transparant-banner">This picture loaded ok.</div>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:error>
          <div class="absolute-full flex flex-center bg-dark" style="color: red">Cannot load image</div>
        </template>
      </q-img>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      picObject: {  "2": "https://images.takeshape.io/86ce9525-f5f2-4e97-81ba-54e8ce933da7/dev/144069dc-7390-4022-aa0f-abba022d3a2f/spec.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat", "3": "https://natureconservancy-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/tnc/nature/en/photos/prescribed_burn_oregon.jpg?crop=0,120,5760,3600&wid=1640&hei=1025&scl=3.5121951219512195", "4": "https://orig11.deviantart.net/1062/f/2015/315/9/6/abstract__7_by_thejsyve1-d9gciwk.jpg", "5": "https://natureconservancy-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/tnc/nature/en/photos/Brown_County_Hills_Leonetti.jpg?crop=33,0,1192,656&wid=4000&hei=2200&scl=0.29818181818181816", "6": "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/galleries/travel/destinations/northamerica/usa/US%20national%20parks/AP84847745_Yosemite_General-xlarge.jpg", "7": "http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Papaverous-path.jpg", "8": "https://dehayf5mhw1h7.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/183/2016/09/15173325/Brown_County_Indiana_Estados_Unidos_2012-10-14_DD_10.jpg", "9": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/19/e9/58/19e9581dbdc756a2dbbb38ae39a3419c.jpg", "12": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/green-1072828_960_720.jpg","13": "https://www.alwareness.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Bomen-Bos.jpg", "13": "https://www.campz.be/info/wp-content/uploads/header-pic-mountain.jpeg", "14": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUzRyiSPfzeIogLgkY1P8ugrvzls23SMhOcJi7vmUfCe4r1nKa", "14": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg", "15": "https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5720/22076039308_4e2fc21c5f_o.jpg" }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    reportError(event) {
      console.log(`${event.name}: ${event.message}`);
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style>
.transparant-banner {
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

On Chrome browser I get errors on several of the images. See:

[image]
On Firefox everything works as expected. Quasar [relies](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/e0910dacf7b68cc1ce5d4e2219ff7df8393bbe05/ui/src/components/img/QImg.js#L128) in its `q-img` component on the javascript `image()` with its `onerror` which apparently is triggered.

My questions:

1. Why are errors triggered as they seem random and since the image
   does show it is successfully downloaded (after the error occurs)?
2. How can I solve this?

[This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/p1bce4fw/31/) shows the behavior, relevant code in `components/Example.vue`.

EDIT:
The errormessage is: `EncodingError - The source image cannot be decoded.`

[Apparently .decode() causes the error](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-img-decode). But what is the exact reason? 
This [article](https://usefulangle.com/post/123/javascript-pre-load-decode-image) describes `.decode()` and it indeed only applies to Chrome. In Quasar the decode is dealt with [here](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/6b7fd29a344b1ddaa02ebd5319a3bb6877ed14e7/ui/src/components/img/QImg.js#L141).

Comment: Additional info from sandbox: EncodingError - The source image cannot be decoded.

Comment: @Caramiriel Yeah, any idea why it can not be decoded? Since all pictures can have successful downloads as well...

Comment: @Caramiriel Maybe you can also tell me where you find that exact errormessage in codesandbox as I can not find it...?!

Comment: What can be done is to add a breakpoint near where you're logging the error. If that isn't possible, you can add `debugger;` as statement, and it will trigger a breakpoint for you whenever it reaches that location. I have no clue why the error is occurring though.

Comment: @musicformellons, do you have this page opened in browser (public)?

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy What do you mean? What page?

Comment: @musicformellons with this code, of course. Sandbox is a bad choice if you want to debug.

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy Your point being? You prefer a jsfiddle?

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy Changed it into a more lightweight jsfiddle showing exact same behavior.

Comment: @musicformellons, the thing is I wanted to deep dive into this issue on real app. Ok, if you don't have it public, np. I'll take a look

Comment: @musicformellons, I've moved all scripts at the bottom of body. And every image loads correctly for me in Chrome.

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy I tried something based on your suggestion, but does not work. Can you fork the fiddle, adjust it and post a link to the working version?

Comment: @musicformellons, I've noticed the issue eventually. Let me explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image.decode is async browser api which is supposed to avoid conditions of main thread being blocked while decoding and painting.

What happens when these images are initialized with src? Browser starts to download them. Decode gives you a Promise to know when it can be safely inserted into the DOM.

But when you process sequentially some number of huge images (like in the example, each one is around 4mb), it gets corrupted sometimes. Not sure why, but size and number do matter.

I've played with your images array with simple code, like

```js
imagesArray.forEach(function(img) {
  var i = new Image();
  i.src = img;
  i.decode().then(function() {
    console.log("decoded");
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log("error");
  });
});
```

And error is easy to get with more than 5-6 images. I would suggest trying with static images (image Content-type) instead.

Anyway, Quazar uses `this.__updateSrc();` to pass src value to the backgroundImage. That is why backgrounds are loaded even for the error cases. It makes the browser download these images twice! In error cases, the first download of the image, using decoding, is not used.

If you want to put this error down, comment out the line with `this.hasError = true` inside [__onError](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/6b7fd29a344b1ddaa02ebd5319a3bb6877ed14e7/ui/src/components/img/QImg.js#L86). This property when true triggers Vue to throw an error for template slot.

By the way, in version v1.0.0-rc.1 of Quasar this issue is [solved](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/4167), i.e. it will download without error status.

Comment: I updated the fiddle with various pictures and indeed the large ones fail!

Answer (score 1):

You will notice, using the DevTools Network, that the vue downloaded images (later batch) are staged, with no more than 6 downloaded at a time. The HTTP common-sense limit for simultaneous open connections is 2. You will also notice that the quasar loaded images don't follow this rule: they are all (12) downloaded in parallel. In Firefox, they are all forcefully constrained to 2 at a time. What I assume happens (the only proof being that the same image is downloaded with different byte sizes, if you notice) is that the large number of parallel quasar connections get reset by the remote server in-flight (as the header is still 200).